# Angular momentum uncertainty principle and the particle on a ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

By considering a particle on a ring, the eigenfunctions of $H$ are also eigenfunctions of $L_\text{z}$:

$$\psi(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{im\phi}$$

with $m = 0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$. In polar coordinates, the corresponding operators are

$$H = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2I}\frac{d^{2}}{d\phi^{2}}$$ $$L_\text{z} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$$

The Robertson version of uncertainty principle, valid in a statistical sense, tell us

$$\Delta L_{x}\Delta L_\text{y} \geq \frac{1}{2}\left | \int \psi^{*}[L_{x},L_{y}]\psi d\tau\right | $$ where usually $[L_{x},L_{y}] = i\hbar L_{z}$. The operators for $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$ are

$$L_{x} = i\hbar \left (  sin(\phi)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + cot(\theta)sin(\phi)\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right )$$

$$L_{y} = -i\hbar \left (  cos(\phi)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} - cot(\theta)sin(\phi)\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right )$$

Since the ring plane is located on xy plane, i.e $\theta = \pi/2$, we obtain

$$L_{x}\psi = L_{y}\psi = 0$$

This make sense, since the particle is rotating around z-axis. Then, $[L_{x},L_{y}]\psi = 0$? Thus, in this specific case, doesn't the relation $[L_{x},L_{y}] = i\hbar L_{z}$ hold? The interpretation of uncertainty principle is valid for a complete set of eigenfunctions of two operators, but can exist some eigenfunctions of $L_{z}$ which are eigenfunctions of $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$ (the above with 0 eigenvalue). Does it means that $[L_{x},L_{y}] = i\hbar L_{z}$ should be use with care? Why? Is it valid only when $[L_{x},L_{y}]\psi \neq 0$?

Comment: The question seems very confused. Yes, there is a common eigenstate of $L_x,L_y,L_z,L^2$ --this in no way is in conflict with the HUP. See e.g.[here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450956/if-l-z-has-a-0-eigenfunction-since-l-x-l-y-i-hbar-l-z-then-can-l).

Comment: The zero-angular momentum state $|00\rangle$ ($l=0$, $m=0$) is an eigenstate of $L^2$, $L_z$, $L_x$, and $L_y$. It is in fact the *only* simultaneous eigenstate of all of these operators. I don't agree, though, that $L_x$ and $L_y$ acting on the state you've written down is 0.  Maybe it's *expectation value* is zero, but not just the operators acting on the states.

Comment: Since you've restricted the particles to have $\theta=\pi/2$, this means that if you were to expand your state in the spherical harmonics (which you would need to do in order to figure out what $L_x$ and $L_y$ do to that state!), you would get a *lot* of them in the expansion with large coefficients. Alternatively, what you could say is that by restricting the particle to only depend on $\phi$, $L_x$ and $L_y$ aren't operators on the space of states you're considering.

Comment: @march, test the operators on the state. Since $\theta=\pi/2$, $cot(\theta) = 0$. Since there is no $\theta$ dependence on $\psi(\phi)$, $\partial\psi/\partial\theta = 0$. In this case, $L_{x}\psi = 0$ and $L_{y}\psi=0$, no? The restriction would be because the ring is on the xy plane. But, even in this case, $\mathbf{L}$ seems to be in line with $L_z$... What about the Robertson uncertainty principle?

Comment: @TobiasFünke there it is wrote: "If a common eigenvector exists for Lx,Ly it must have eigenvalue 0 simultaneously for Lx,Ly,Lz and also L2;" But, in the case of particle on a ring, since the motion is in xy plane, only $L_{z}$ survive, right? And, in this case, would the total angular momentum be equal to $L_{z}$? I wrote the $L^{2}$ operator and act it on \psi.

Comment: If you work on $S^1$, the unit-torus, then there are no $L_x,L_y$ operators, just as  @march pointed out already.

Comment: @TobiasFünke but, and in the ring located on xy-plane in a given coordinate system?

Comment: It seems that you are confusing the fact that the angular momentum operator in 3-D has components in the $x$ and $y$ direction, while in the 2-D plane you are considering there is only a single rotational axis that is relevant. There is, therefore, really no sense in talking about rotations with respect to axes that you cannot even rotate around and still remain in 2-D!

Comment: @MattHanson but, to say that "there is only the z-axis", this would mean that $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$ are zero, not? And, in this case, we would be both these components with 0 value, because angular momentum is a vector quantity, no?

Comment: You are really just solving the Schrodinger equation in 2D with the laplacian written in plane polar coordinates and the domain restricted such that $r$ is a constant. That’s where you’re getting the relevant angular derivative from, not the 3D angular momentum $z$ component, though the two are very similar for obvious reasons.

Comment: @TobiasFünke $S^1$ is the usual notation for the unit circle, the "doughnut" torus is: $S^1\times S^1$.